# colorbox two links at image but display once in group

Tags: javascript, colorbox

i have 2 different link to same image of a group for each image
bu i would like to view the photo only once in my group navigation

```
<a href="myimg1.jpg" class="img-gallery" rel="gallery"><img src="img-place-holder.jpg"></a>
<a href="myimg1.jpg" class="img-gallery" rel="gallery">open my image</a>

<a href="myimg2.jpg" class="img-gallery" rel="gallery"><img src="img-place-holder.jpg"></a>
<a href="myimg2.jpg" class="img-gallery" rel="gallery">open my image</a>
```

with this code i found 4 images in my gallery instead of 2

Answer (score -1):

I found a way to solve this on Colorbox FAQ: http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/faq/#faq-click It is not copy/paste and go, but might put you on the right direction.

```
var $gallery = $("a[rel=gallery]").colorbox();
$("a#openGallery").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $gallery.eq(0).click();
});
```

It is important to remove `rel` attribute on your gallery button (which prevents the duplication of the image).

Comment: Why downvote, it worked for me, unless I had missed the point of the question in the first place?

Comment: I wasn't the downvoter, but it could have been that before you edited in an example you had posted a short, link-only answer. Such answers often get downvoted and deleted.

Comment: Aha, thanks for explanation, I did it exactly that bad (was so horny to answer). Will be more patient and precise next time.